# Detecting when a DOM element's parent changes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a DOM event that fires when an element's `parentElement` changes? If not, is there any way better than polling with a timeout?

I'm specifically interesting in knowing when the `parentElement` changes from `null` to some defined element. That is, when a DOM element is attached to the document tree somewhere.

**EDIT**

Given the questions in the comments, here is an example that shows how to create an element with a `null` `parentElement`:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');

console.assert(element.parentElement == null);
```

The parent is only set once it's added to the DOM:

```
document.body.appendChild(element);

console.assert(element.parentElement != null);
```

Note too that elements created using jQuery will also have a `null` parent when created:

```
console.assert($('<div></div>').get(0).parentElement == null);
```

Comment: You are trying to listen if an element get wrapped in another ?

Comment: How can a parentElement can be null if the child is already in the DOM? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, that's also my question, all elements will have at least the html element as parent ?

Comment: @Krumia @enguerranws  parent of a newly created element is `null`. OP is interested in the `moment` when it is attached to DOM and parent `changes from null to someElement.`

Comment: See my edit for clarification .

Comment: `Object.observe()` won't work because `parentElement` isn't an own property. Would you like to set a `MutationObserver` on documentElement and in all reports coming figure out if your special element is inside?

Comment: @MartinErnst, I haven't seen [the MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) before. It looks interesting, but I'm not sure how scalable it would be to observe every change to the `childList` of every node of the document tree on a busy page with many updates. I'm building library code, so would like to be conservative in my assumptions about what a user is doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a MutationObserver like this:

```js
const trackedElement = document.getElementById('tracked-element');
const parent1 = document.getElementById('parent1');
const parent2 = document.getElementById('parent2');
startObserver();

function changeParent() {
  if (trackedElement.parentElement == parent1) {
    parent1.removeChild(trackedElement);
    parent2.appendChild(trackedElement);
  } else {
    parent2.removeChild(trackedElement);
    parent1.appendChild(trackedElement);
  }
}

function startObserver() {
  let parentElement = trackedElement.parentElement

  new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (!parentElement.contains(trackedElement)) {
      trackedElement.textContent = "Parent changed";
      setTimeout(() => {
        trackedElement.textContent = "Parent not changed";
      }, 500);

      startObserver();
      this.disconnect();
    }
  }).observe(parentElement, {
    childList: true
  });
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div id="parent1">
    <p id="tracked-element">Parent not changed</p>
  </div>

  <div id="parent2"></div>

  <button onclick="changeParent()">ChangeParent</button>
</body>

</html>
```

You can right click on the `Parent not changed` text and click inspect to make sure that it is actually changing parents

If you want to know how the `.observer` function works, there's VERY good documentation on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe

Answer (score 2):

Afaik there's no such "parent listener".

Yet, I found a hack that might be helpful. At least it's worth reading, since the idea is clever.

http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/04/25/i-want-a-damnodeinserted/

He uses CSS @keyframes during the insertion and listens for the resulting animation event which tells him, that the element got inserted.

Comment: Please add a summary of that external resource here, otherwise when (not 'if') that page dies your answer becomes immediately useless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is definitely an interesting idea. It's a shame to have to resort to this though. Welcome to SO btw :)

Comment: Misusing an animation timer for a listener is bad idea and results in bad code. No way I'm gonna use that.

Comment: @Bitterblue What are you using (did you use) instead of that?

Comment: @trusktr I don't remember. Maybe I didn't find a solution. Maybe I worked around the need for a parent listener. Most of the time you don't need the feature which involves hacks.

Answer (score 1):

1) Such a `parentElementHasChanged event` doesn't exist.

2) The workaround **PISquared** pointed to would work but looks very strange to me.

3) In practise there is no need for such an event. A parentChange would only appear to an element if it's position in the DOM changes.To make this happen you have to run some code on the element doing this, and all that code has to use native `parent.removeChild()`,
`parent.appendChild`, `parent.insertBefore()` or `parent.replaceChild()` somewhere. The same code could run a callback afterwards so the callback would be the event.

4) You are building library code. The library could provide a single function for all DOM-insertions/removals, which wraps the four native functions and "triggers the event". That's the last and only what comes in my mind to avoid a frequently lookup for parentElement.

5) If there's a need to include the native `Event API`, you may create a **parentChanged** event with [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)

```
element.addEventListener('parentChanged', handler); // only when  Event API needed

function manipulateElementsDOMPosition(element, target, childIndex, callback, detail) {
    if (!target.nodeType) {
        if (arguments.length > 4) return element;
        detail = callback; callback = childIndex; childIndex = target; target = null;
    }
    if (typeof childIndex === 'function') detail = callback, callback = childIndex;
    var oldParent = element.parentElement,
        newParent = target,
        sameParent = oldParent === newParent,
        children = newParent.children,
        cl = children.length,
        ix = sameParent && cl && [].indexOf.call(children, element),
        validPos = typeof childIndex === 'number' && cl <= childIndex;
    if (childIndex === 'replace') {
        (newParent = target.parentElement).replaceChild(element, target);
        if (sameParent) return element;
    } else {
        if (samePar) {
            if (!oldParent || ix == childIndex ||
                childIndex === 'first' && ix === 0 ||
                childIndex === 'last' && ix === (cl - 1)) return element;
            oldParent.removeChild(element);
        } else if (oldParent) oldParent.removeChild(element);
        if (!cl || childIndex === 'last') {
            newParent.appendChild(element);
        } else if (childIndex === 'first') {
            newParent.insertBefore(element, children[0])
        } else if (validPos) {
            newParent.insertBefore(element, children[childIndex]);
        } else return element;      
    }
    console.log(element, 'parentElement has changed from: ', oldParent, 'to: ', newParent);
    element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('parentChanged', detail)); // only when Event API needed
    if (typeof callback === 'function') callback.call(element, oldParent, newParent, detail);
    return element;
}
```

some example usage (detail may be anything you want to pass to the event/callback). Function always return element.

```
// remove element
manipulateElementsDOMPosition(element /*optional:*/, callback, detail);
// prepend element in target
manipulateElementsDOMPosition(element, target, 'first' /*optional:*/, callback, detail);
// append element in target
manipulateElementsDOMPosition(element, target, 'last' /*optional:*/, callback, detail);
// add element as third child of target, do nothing when less than two children there
manipulateElementsDOMPosition(element, target, 3 /*optional:*/, callback, detail);
// replace a target-element with element
manipulateElementsDOMPosition(element, target, 'replace' /*optional:*/, callback, detail);
```